# Build c# Generic Type definition at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, types

At present I'm having to do something like this to build a Type definition at runtime to pass to my IOC to resolve. Simplified:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleApplication2.Program+Person");
```

I know the generic type argument at runtime only.

Is there something that will allow me to do something like this (fake code):

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeWithGenericTypeArguments(
    typeof(List)
    , passInType.GetType());
```

Or shall I just stick to my hack, `passInType.GetType()` convert to string, build generic type string.. feel dirty

Comment: I feel dirty just reading your code sample.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`MakeGenericType` - i.e.

```
Type passInType = ... /// perhaps myAssembly.GetType(
        "ConsoleApplication2.Program+Person")
Type t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(passInType);
```

For a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
 class Program {
   class Person {}
   static void Main(){
       Assembly myAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
       Type passInType = myAssembly.GetType(
           "ConsoleApplication2.Program+Person");
       Type t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(passInType);
   }
 }
}
```

---

As suggested in the comments - to explain, `List<>` is the *open* generic type - i.e. "`List<T>` without any specific `T`" (for multiple generic types, you just use commas - i.e. `Dictionary<,>`). When a `T` is specified (either through code, or via `MakeGenericType`) we get the *closed* generic type - for example, `List<int>`.

When using `MakeGenericType`, any generic type constraints are still enforced, but simply at runtime rather than at compile time.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add explanation of open/closed generic types for completeness.

Comment: MakeGenericType was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :) Answer accepted